# Handle an event in a form created in a class in C #

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Please help me,

I need  to use in a form the OnTickHistoryResponse event so when the event happens I can show information in a control.

The event OnTickHistoryResponse comes with an API called ActivetickFeed and this event OnTickHistoryResponse is already in the API, please your help, I do not know how I can use the event.

Only this appears in the documentation:[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzmxC.png)

The class where the event is defined and assigned a method is this:

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ActiveTickFeedCOMCSExample
{
    class ActiveTickFeed
    {
        public static ActiveTickFeedLib.Feed feed;
        public static ActiveTickFeed instance;

        public ActiveTickFeed()
        {
            //create new instance of IFeed
            feed = new ActiveTickFeedLib.Feed();

            feed.PrimaryServerHostname = "activetick1.activetick.com";
            feed.BackupServerHostname = "activetick2.activetick.com";

            feed.ServerPort = 443;

            //connect all IFeedEvents events to local methods
            
            feed.OnTickHistoryResponse += feed_OnTickHistoryResponse;
            
            }
            
            
            void feed_OnTickHistoryResponse(int originalRequestId, short tickHistoryResponseCode, string symbol, short symbolStatusCode, object records)
        {
            Form1.instance.AddData("Processing OnTickHistoryResponse........");

            Form1.instance.AddData("ATTickHistoryResponseType: " + ((ActiveTickFeedLib.ATTickHistoryResponseEnum)tickHistoryResponseCode).ToString());
            Form1.instance.AddData("ATSymbolStatus: " + ((ActiveTickFeedLib.ATSymbolStatusEnum)symbolStatusCode).ToString());

            switch ((ActiveTickFeedLib.ATTickHistoryResponseEnum)tickHistoryResponseCode)
            {
                case ActiveTickFeedLib.ATTickHistoryResponseEnum.ATTickHistoryResponseSuccess:
                case ActiveTickFeedLib.ATTickHistoryResponseEnum.ATTickHistoryResponseMaxLimitReached:
                    {
                        if ((ActiveTickFeedLib.ATSymbolStatusEnum)symbolStatusCode == ActiveTickFeedLib.ATSymbolStatusEnum.ATSymbolStatusSuccess)
                        {
                            if (records != null)
                            {
                                string[] recordsArray = (string[])records;
                                foreach (string s in recordsArray)
                                    Form1.instance.AddData(s);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case ActiveTickFeedLib.ATTickHistoryResponseEnum.ATTickHistoryResponseInvalidRequest:
                    break;
                case ActiveTickFeedLib.ATTickHistoryResponseEnum.ATTickHistoryResponseDenied:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you send the "SendTickHistoryRequest", as a response you will get "OnTickHistoryResponse" event. So event subscribing is not enough, please send a request (SendTickHistoryRequest) you will get a response event.

Comment: Hello Ravi, please could you provide an example. I can't find the "SendTickHistoryRequest",